# Java automated deployment for desktop applications

Tags: java, deployment, build, auto-update

I have been programming in Java for 3 years, but have mostly been deploying Java applications locally, and thus, have not had a need to think about scale, auto-updating, deployment servers, and the like. I simply used a corporate shared file drive for distribution, and wrapped the jar in an Exe wrapper every time I wanted to push an update.

However, the company I work for wants to scale the Java desktop application I made, and deploy it across departments. This calls in the need for automated deployment, updating, and change tracking. So, for the last week, I have been searching and speaking with a lot of people about the process of automating the deployment of Java applications. Of course, I have found a huge amount of response pertaining to Java EE, tomcat servers, and mostly web based applications. But, what I am looking for is a way to manage Desktop based Java applications, that run from an executable on a user's windows machine.

The question then that I have run into, how is it that I would get started setting up automatic builds, updates, and deployment when I the target audience is running the applications from their desktop as an Exe wrapped jar file? I have found a few articles that reference installers with update based capabilities, but I'm trying to figure out how I can utalize a Java server to autocompile and distribute updates, and all that Jazz. Like I said, I am extremely dumb when it comes to this side of Java and would love any direction that there is to offer. Thanks!

Comment: JNLP is the usual approach for what you want; not sure if it's been killed off or is still current.

Comment: I think one of those got killed off, Java Web Start or the other, but the other one is still supported.  Google "JNLP" will get you started, and a question here on SO more targeted at what you find would also help.

Comment: @markspace It is of my understanding that Java Web Start applications that need to access the file system or network connections require elevated privileges. The company I work for does not provide admin rights to standard users, thus they are not allowed to elevate privileges. Currently, the users are running exe wrapped jar files with standard user privileges, and the program is allowed to make sql calls and access the file system.